# Unable to add more content in main page because grid is full

Tags: wpf

I want more buttons after "hurt status" but the size of grid becomes smaller, so I am unable to do so. Can I use `scrollviewer` to do that or something else?

**[Xaml Code is as Below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RbOk.jpg)**

```
    <Button Content="Angry Status" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="66" Click="Button_Click" Width="400"/>
        <Button Content="Attitude Status" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,79,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="66" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        <Button Content="Awesome Status" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,131,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="66" Click="Button_Click_2" />
        <Button Content="Best Status" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,183,-2,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="66"/>
        <Button Content="Break Up Status" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,235,-2,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="66"/>
        <Button Content="Cool Status" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,279,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="66"/>
        <Button Content="FriendShip Day Status" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,331,-2,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="66"/>
        <Button Content="FriendShip Status" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,383,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="66"/>
        <Button Content="Funny Status" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,435,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="66" />
        <Button Content="Hug Day Status" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,487,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="66"/>
        <Button Content="Hurt Status" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,539,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="66"/>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it with a `ScrollViewer` and you should be good to go. Also,  I'll suggest to use `<Grid.RowDefinitions>` and set each of your `Button` to its `Grid.Row` so that you won't need to set `Margin` property. You need to explicitly set the `MaxHeight`  as the `ScrollViewer` wouldn't know what would be the `ViewPort` for a scrollable area.

```
<ScrollViewer MaxHeight="700">
   <Grid>
        <Button Content="Angry Status" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="66" Click="Button_Click" Width="400"/>
        <Button Content="Attitude Status" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,79,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="66" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        <Button Content="Awesome Status" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,131,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="66" Click="Button_Click_2" />
        <Button Content="Best Status" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,183,-2,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="66"/>
        <Button Content="Break Up Status" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,235,-2,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="66"/>
        <Button Content="Cool Status" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,279,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="66"/>
        <Button Content="FriendShip Day Status" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,331,-2,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="66"/>
        <Button Content="FriendShip Status" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,383,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="66"/>
        <Button Content="Funny Status" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,435,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="66" />
        <Button Content="Hug Day Status" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,487,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="66"/>
        <Button Content="Hurt Status" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,539,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="66"/>
   </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```